# Sample Program for Azure Key Vault Client Library for .NET Tutorial fails with Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

As part of my effort to enhance my ASP.NET Core 3 web app with the ability to use Azure Blob storage, I need to understand the azure key vault.

So I'm following [Quickstart: Azure Key Vault client library for .NET (SDK v4)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net).

The sample code here demonstrates techniques for storing and fetching secrets to/from my key vault. Are these techniques appropriate for use inside of Kubernetes resident ASP.NET Core 3 Kestrel Web Apps? If not, please guide me to some appropriate sample code for fetching and storing secrets.

I enhance the sample console application to print the keyValutName retrieved from the environment variable and it is indeed correct.

I get the following error:

```
dotnet run
Creating a secret in kv-temp called 'mySecret' with the value '3.14159' ...Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details.You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS70002: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.
```

What am I doing wrong? The error says to modify the configuration in application registration portal...  [This seems contrary to what I read in 'App identity and security principles'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/authentication) where the preferred approach is to NOT register the application.

Should I be registering this console application (and my ASP.NETCore Web App) in the azure portal? Should I be creating a principle?

**Fri Oct 09 2020 Update**
I followed Allen's instructions and did the `git clone` and edited the source as per Allen's instructions and I'm getting this (similar) error:

```
MsalServiceException: AADSTS70002: The client does not exist or is not 
enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new 
application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at 
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.
Trace ID: 4700fefb-af1b-4566-bba8-46ccdbac6a00
Correlation ID: 332949b6-7490-44b3-87e6-11163c3a70ec
Timestamp: 2020-10-09 13:49:26Z
```

Thank you

Siegfried

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to try my suggestion?

Comment: Do you still need help on this? Any updates? If my answer is helpful, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I would like help. I responded to your answer in my Oct 9 update. I do not understand why the error message mentions the App Registrations because this is not mentioned in the quickstart. Does it make sense to register a console application running on my desktop? The link in the error message takes me to the AAD app registration page and is prompting for a redirect URL! This is a console app, not a webapp. Do keyvaults use AAD? It is also prompting for a user facing display name. Where/how is this used? I don't se it in the quick-start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET Core 3.1 SDK or later, I think these techniques apply to your application. See [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net#prerequisites).

Based on [Authenticate and create a client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net#authenticate-and-create-a-client), The sample console application is using Default Azure Credential Authentication.

So you don't need to create a service principal here. The 'DefaultAzureCredential()' class will read your Azure credential.

I didn't repro your issue. But here are my simple steps to run it.

Download the entire console app from [Getting Started with Azure Key Vault with .NET Core](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-core-quickstart).

Use Visual Studio to open the project and then sign in VS with your Azure account. Make sure this account has access to your Azure Key Vault.

Replace `string keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");` with `string keyVaultName = "{your own key vault name}";` `{your own key vault name}` should be an existing key vault which you have created.

Then you should be able to run it successfully. The `DefaultAzureCredential()` will read your Azure credential in VS and it doesn't require you to create a service principal.